# Django views testing , RequestFactory with data

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have this view:

```
def send_results(request):
    print request
    if request.is_ajax():
        address = request.POST.get('url')
    process_data(address)
    context = get_all_from_database()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

and I need to test it:

```
    def test_send_results(self):
        factory = RequestFactory()
        request = factory.get('/views/send_results')
        response = send_results(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But it always stop with error that in my view 'address' value is referensed before asignment. How to pass it some value ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `request.is_ajax()` is `False` then `address` will not be assigned before `process_data(address)` is called. If you want to test an AJAX request then you should pass the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header:

```
request = factory.get('/views/send_results', HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
```

However you'll still need to fix your view to handle the case when the request is not an AJAX request.

Comment: It still raises error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout' on the same line

Comment: Then you most likely have a bug in your `process_data` function.